# Where should I validate if user has access to resource?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I am building a Rest API with Java spring, to secure the endpoint I have implemented authentication based on JWT.

I have set up a filter where I validate the token and recover the user along with a role. So far this is working great however, I don't know where should I implement the authorization based on the user and role.

For instance:
if x is admin, he/she can hit any endpoint
if y is user with id 1, she/he can hit only hers/his resources; e.g. /user/1/books.

I am inclined to do this authorization in the same filter where I validate the JWT, however, I will have to parse the url to find if it is going the right endpoint. The other possibility is to implemented directly in the controller but I don't like this approach as I feel this overwhelms the controller business logic.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Did you search for anything?  Maybe https://www.developer.com/security/article.php/3467801/Securing-J2EE-Applications-with-a-Servlet-Filter.htm

Comment: Yes, I did. I was thinking about implementing in a filter as I mentioned. The downside is that for my case I will have to parse the url.

Comment: Spring has an entire infrastructure built for this specific purpose. Use `@PreAuthorize`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged "spring-security" i assume that you are using it ;-).

You can use a lot of spring build-in checks to perform your preverred check. You are able to use @PreAuthorize @PostAuthorize and EL-checks in your service annotations. 
I think spring will use it as an additional filter chain, but i don´t know it exactly. If the check is not processed successfull, spring will return a 4xx status code.

```
@PreAuthorize("@someBean.someCheck(authentication)")
public void yourServiceMethod(...)
```

(The authentication object is mapped by spring)

```
public boolean someCheck(Authentication auth)
```

See also:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/el-access.html
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions-basic